# How I can update the environment table in pytest-html

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-html

I am trying to edit the default pytest-html report and want to update Environment table.

I need to add the rows for browser, Application URL and other variable in environment table and delete some default rows.

I have used to add extra variable in environment table

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='session')
def _environment(request):
    request.config._metadata['URL']=os.environ['url']
```

However when I add multiple metadata variable it throws an error

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='session')
def _environment(request):
    request.config._metadata['URL']=os.environ['url']
    request.config._metadata['Browser']=os.environ['browser']
```

Can anyone help me to achieve it

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [docs](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-html#environment), Environment section can be accessed via the pytest_configure hook.
The following works for me with pytest 4.4.0

```
def pytest_configure(config):
    config._metadata['URL'] = os.environ['url']
    config._metadata['Browser'] = os.environ['browser']
```

Answer (score 0):

As of pytest v6.x.x, This no longer works, the builtin fixture is called pytestconfig:

```
def test01_just_a_test(pytestconfig):
    pytestconfig._metadata['URL'] = os.environ['url']
    pytestconfig._metadata['Browser'] = os.environ['browser']
```

But the documentation is not updated.

Comment: How would you set it globally, like in conftest.py?

Comment: @Marc, pytestconfig is a predefined fixture to use from inside your tests, in conftest.py you can create fixtures to use with your tests. I have one called params where I delete autoadded env variables I do not want to display, but it is better to use pytestconfig